# find same value in 2 differents column from differents files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, grep

I got 2 files:

file1.txt:

```
1 A bla 9232
1 B tesfs 3049
1 C blof 4054
2 D dkeeez 3049
2 E eor 4042
3 F foaer 4024
```

file2.txt:

```
A
B
E
```

Expected output, file3.txt:

```
1 A bla 9232
1 B tesfs 3049
2 E eor 4042
```

The output is simply the line from the file1 that contains the same value in column 2 than in the file2.

In file2.txt, each line is unique, but you can have :

```
A
AA
AAee
B
...
```

I tried to used grep -Ff file2.txt file1.txt but there's still line in file3.txt that doesn't exist in file2.txt
The solution can be in line or in a shell script, I tried to use "awk" and  shell script, without result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2.txt file1.txt
```

In the first iteration we store all values from `file2.txt` into an array `a`. In the 2nd step white iterating `file1.txt` we check if column 2 is in array `a` and print it.

**Output:**

```
1 A bla 9232
1 B tesfs 3049
2 E eor 4042
```

Comment: yes it's worked perfectly, even with not tried list (I didn't specify in my question that the file could be not tried sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

This is one thing that `join` is good for, provided your inputs are sorted (on field 2 for `file1.txt`, and on field 1 for `file2.txt` - your example shows sorted inputs, but if your real inputs aren't, you'll have to fix that before `join` will work):

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: This solutions worked perfectly too, but I didn't specify that the file can sometime not be sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I love the awk solution from anubbhava. Here is an alternate solution, using grep:

```
# Add word anchors before and after each word in file2.txt
sed 's/^/\\b/;s/$/\\b/' file2.txt > temp.txt  

grep -f temp.txt file1.txt
rm temp.txt
```

The file *temp.txt* would look like this:

```
\bA\b
\bB\b
\bE\b
```

Next, we would use that *temp.txt* file as the search terms and get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

## grep + awk version:

```
# This will grep the first column of file2.txt in file1.txt. 

grep "`awk '{print $1}' file2.txt`" file1.txt
1 A bla 9232
1 B tesfs 3049
2 E eor 4042
```

## grep + cut version:

```
# This will grep the first column of file2.txt in file1.txt. 

grep "`cut -d' ' -f1 file2.txt`" file1.txt

1 A bla 9232
1 B tesfs 3049
2 E eor 4042
```